# Getting a reference to the object that holds a property that is a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

The title is really confusing, I couldn't find a better one.

Suppose I have:

```
var A = function (){
    this.pa = { x: 1 };
};

A.prototype.B = function (){
    this.pb = /* a reference to { x: 1 } */;
};

var a = new A ();
var b = new a.B ();
console.log (b.pb.x); //should print 1
a.pa.x = 2;
console.log (b.pb.x); //should print 2
```

I want to save in `pb` a reference to the `pa` object. Is it possible?

Comment: `new a.B` does not create a relationship between the new instance of `A.prototype.B` and `a`.  Constructor calls are very different from method calls in that they do not receive a reference to the method target.

Comment: That's why I am asking. Any hack to get a reference to `a`?

Comment: You could make `b` a getter property that returns a bound curried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly what I want but it's very close:

```
var A = function (pa){
    this.pa = pa;
};

A.prototype.B = function (a){
    if (this instanceof A.prototype.B){
        if (!a) throw "error";
        this.pb = a.pa;
        return;
    }
    return new A.prototype.B (this);
};

var a = new A ({ x: 1 });
var b = a.B ();
console.log (b.pb.x); //1
a.pa.x = 2;
console.log (b.pb.x); //2

new a.B () //throws "error"
```

Comment: This does not work if you assign `new A` to anything else than `a`.

Comment: Can you elaborate the comment? I don't understand :)

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked that `a` was a parameter of the constructor and that you passed something in.

Answer (score 1):

A function [used as a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) has only a reference to the new instance, inheriting from its prototype.

To make it maintain a reference to the original `A` instance, you will need to put the `B` constructor in a closure:

```
function A() {
    var that = this;
    this.pa = { x: 1 };

    this.B = function() {
        this.pb = that.pa;
    };
};

var a = new A ();
var b = new a.B ();
console.log (b.pb.x); // does print 1
a.pa.x = 2;
console.log (b.pb.x); // does print 2
```

However, this has the disadvantage of creating a new `B` constructor (with its own prototype object) for every single `A` instance. Better would be something like

```
function A() {
    this.pa = { x: 1 };
}
A.B = function() {
    this.pb = null;
};
A.prototype.makeB = function() {
    var b = new A.B();
    b.pb = this.pa;
    return b;
};
// you can modify the common A.B.prototype as well

var a = new A ();
var b = a.makeB();
console.log (b.pb.x); // does print 1
a.pa.x = 2;
console.log (b.pb.x); // does print 2
```

Yet, we could mix the two approaches so that you have only one prototype but different constructors:

```
function A() {
    var that = this;
    this.pa = { x: 1 };

    this.B = function() {
        this.pb = that.pa;
    };
    this.B.prototype = A.Bproto;
}
A.Bproto = {
    …
};
```

Comment: I cannot use the second option because a method of `B` is called `create()`. In fact, the real name of `B` is `User`, so I cannot instantiate a user with a method called `makeUser()`, `createUser()`, `newUser()` or `newUserInstance()`; it's a matter of design

Comment: The first option it's really what I want to achieve but I have to create the prototype functions of `B` inside the `A` constructor. Every time `new A` is called a new prototype of `B` is created. I could use this solution because it's valid and works but it's inneficient and takes me back to the past, at the early ages when I was starting learning javascript and doing ugly things like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = function (){
    this.pa = { x: 1 };
};

A.prototype.B = function (a){

     this.pb = a.pa;
};
var a = new A ();

var b = new  a.B(a);
console.log(b.pb.x); //should print 1
a.pa.x = 2;
console.log(b.pb.x);
```

Comment: This does not work if you assign `new A` to anything else than `a`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding you but can u explain what do u mean by this will not work if u assign new A to anything else than a. Because although your solution is more elegant, isn't your B is still tied to an specific instance of A?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely overlooked that `a` was a parameter to your `B` constructor; I had assumed you tried to access the global `a` variable.